# How should I distribute data files with Perl modules?

Tags: perl, cpan

I've started a `module-starter` (with `--builder=Module::Build`).  I want to use `SQL::Library` to collect my SQL into an .ini file... but in order to find the file during run time, I need to know its exact path.  How do I get the path of the "data directory" of a module at run time?

Until now, I've been using FindBin (like `"$FindBin::Bin/../../path/to/module/datafiles/foo.ini"`, but I found this is not very robust (For example, it seems to break when there are two programs with the same name in two different dirs in PATH).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is what [File::ShareDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ShareDir) is for.  Since you're using Module::Build, you'll need to set the [share_dir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module::Build::API#share_dir) parameter (and require Module::Build 0.36) in order to have your data files installed along with your module.  Then, in your code, you'll use File::ShareDir to calculate the path of `foo.ini` (e.g. `dist_file('My-Dist', 'foo.ini')`)

Comment: Can I get `File::ShareDir` to find files when the module is not yet installed, from scripts in bin/ or test files?

Comment: @user1481, Scripts run through `Build test` will find the file because the module is installed (in `blib/`) when those tests are run.

Comment: @user1481, For other scripts, either do `perl Build.PL && ./Build && perl -Mblib script.pl` or add code to fallback to `"$FindBin::Bin/../share/foo.ini"` if the file returned by File::ShareDir doesn't exist.

Comment: File::Share works exactly as File::ShareDir, but can see the ./share directory during development without needing to install.