# How to include a data file with a Perl module?

Tags: perl, perl-module, directory-structure, data-files

What is the "proper" way to bundle a required-at-runtime data file with a Perl module, such that the module can read its contents before being used?

A simple example would be this Dictionary module, which needs to read a list of (word,definition) pairs at startup.

```
package Reference::Dictionary;

# TODO: This is the Dictionary, which needs to be populated from
#  data-file BEFORE calling Lookup!
our %Dictionary;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  return bless {}, $class;
}

sub Lookup {
  my ($self,$word) = @_;
  return $Dictionary{$word};
}
1;
```

and a driver program, Main.pl:

```
use Reference::Dictionary;

my $dictionary = new Reference::Dictionary;
print $dictionary->Lookup("aardvark");
```

Now, my directory structure looks like this:

```
root/
  Main.pl
  Reference/
    Dictionary.pm
    Dictionary.txt
```

I can't seem to get Dictionary.pm to load Dictionary.txt at startup.  I've tried a few methods to get this to work, such as...

- Using BEGIN block:

  ```
  BEGIN {
    open(FP, '<', 'Dictionary.txt') or die "Can't open: $!\n";
    while (<FP>) {
      chomp;
      my ($word, $def) = split(/,/);
      $Dictionary{$word} = $def;
    }
    close(FP);
  }
  ```

  No dice: Perl is looking in cwd for Dictionary.txt, which is the path of the main script ("Main.pl"), not the path of the module, so this gives File Not Found.
- Using DATA:

  ```
  BEGIN {
    while (<DATA>) {
      chomp;
      my ($word, $def) = split(/,/);
      $Dictionary{$word} = $def;
    }
    close(DATA);
  }
  ```

  and at end of module

  ```
  __DATA__
  aardvark,an animal which is definitely not an anteater
  abacus,an oldschool calculator
  ...
  ```

  This too fails because BEGIN executes at compile-time, before **DATA** is available.
- Hard-code the data in the module

  ```
  our %Dictionary = (
    aardvark => 'an animal which is definitely not an anteater',
    abacus => 'an oldschool calculator'
    ...
  );
  ```

  Works, but is decidedly non-maintainable.

Similar question here: [How should I distribute data files with Perl modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286023/how-should-i-distribute-data-files-with-perl-modules) but that one deals with modules installed by CPAN, not modules relative to the current script as I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Note that prototypes (ie. `sub new()`) have *no effect* on methods. They're not function signatures, [they're something completely different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297034/why-are-perl-5s-function-prototypes-bad). Don't use them unless you know what you're doing. If you want function signatures consider [Method::Signatures](https://metacpan.org/pod/Method::Signatures), [Kavorka](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kavorka) or [Function::Parameters](https://metacpan.org/pod/Function::Parameters).

Comment: I suggest using `DATA` with `INIT` instead of `BEGIN` to ensure that the data is initialised before run time. It also makers it more self-documenting

Comment: @Schwern oops my bad, too much C/C++ lately!  I'll edit to remove these.

Comment: You should also avoid using capital  letters in method identifiers. They are reserved for Perl globals such as the package name, so your `sub Lookup` should be `sub lookup`

Comment: @Borodin Upper case method names aren't reserved. It's not normal Perl style, but they're not reserved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to load the dictionary at `BEGIN` time.  `BEGIN` time is relative to the file being loaded.  When your `main.pl` says `use Dictionary`, all the code in Dictionary.pm is compiled and loaded.  Put the code to load it early in Dictionary.pm.

```
package Dictionary;

use strict;
use warnings;

my %Dictionary;  # There is no need for a global
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($word, $def) = split(/,/);
    $Dictionary{$word} = $def;
}
```

You can also load from `Dictionary.txt` located in the same directory.  The trick is you have to provide an absolute path to the file.  You can get this from `__FILE__` which is the path to the current file (ie. `Dictionary.pm`).

```
use File::Basename;

# Get the directory Dictionary.pm is located in.
my $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

open(my $fh, '<', "$dir/Dictionary.txt") or die "Can't open: $!\n";

my %Dictionary;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($word, $def) = split(/,/);
    $Dictionary{$word} = $def;
}
close($fh);
```

Which should you use?  `DATA` is easier to distribute.  A separate, parallel file is easier for non-coders to work on.

---

Better than loading the whole dictionary when the library is loaded, it is more polite to wait to load it when it's needed.

```
use File::Basename;

# Load the dictionary from Dictionary.txt
sub _load_dictionary {
    my %dictionary;

    # Get the directory Dictionary.pm is located in.
    my $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

    open(my $fh, '<', "$dir/Dictionary.txt") or die "Can't open: $!\n";

    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        my ($word, $def) = split(/,/);
        $dictionary{$word} = $def;
    }

    return \%dictionary;
}

# Get the possibly cached dictionary
my $Dictionary;
sub _get_dictionary {
    return $Dictionary ||= _load_dictionary;
}

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = bless {}, $class;
    $self->{dictionary} = $self->_get_dictionary;

    return $self;
}

sub lookup {
    my $self = shift;
    my $word = shift;

    return $self->{dictionary}{$word};
}
```

Each object now contains a reference to the shared dictionary (eliminating the need for a global) which is only loaded when an object is created.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `DATA` with [`INIT` instead of `BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END) to ensure that the data is initialised before run time. It also makers it more self-documenting

Or it may be more appropriate to use a `UNITCHECK` block, which will  be executed as early as possible, immediately after the library file is compiled, and so can be considered as an extension of the compilation

```
package Dictionary;

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dictionary;
UNITCHECK {
    while ( <DATA> ) {
        chomp;
        my ($k, $v) = split /,/;
        $dictionary{$k} = $v;
    }
}
```